# Sublime Text 3 theme like Chrome Inspector 'Dark'

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, sublimetext3

Is there any Sublime Text theme that has the same colors as the Chrome Inspector in its dark flavor?

[image]

Comment: is it really so hard to google "sublime text 3 dark theme"?

Comment: there are many, no one has the same colors, that's why I'm asking.

Comment: but SO is not for asking to find software

Comment: I'm asking about a theme, not about software. Besides, are you aware you're wasting your time saying the obvious instead of doing a search on google at my place ? :)

Comment: So a theme is not a piece of software? SO is not the place to ask for recommendations for tools or software, if you would have read the rules or articles on how to ask, you'd know that. I'm not wasting my time, I believe there is hope for everybody, even when they are resistant and impolite :)

Comment: You would probably be more successful in finding your theme or people having too much time doing the work and search it for you on reddit

Comment: THAT helps. thank you! :)

Comment: Questions asking us to **recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource** are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254393) and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: @MattDMo, I agree this is not a productive question. But many times, even questions that seems unproductive proves to be useful to someone in some case. I have seen stackoverflow have closed many questions which they think are not useful. But often users tend to stumble upon these and find them useful. So I think SO should reconsider their view regarding such question.

Comment: @iiR There is discussion about this periodically on [meta] and [meta.se]. You can also read through the Our Model section in the [help]. Basically, the decision has been made and reaffirmed time and time again that this is how the community wants to run the site, and I agree. Stack Overflow is about *specific* questions getting *specific* answers, direct and to the point, without devolving into a discussion-like forum. There are plenty of forums already out there, including the Sublime Text Forum, where questions like these are quite welcome. SO just isn't one of them.

Comment: @MattDMo, Thank you for explaining. I must agree to what you said to some point.

Comment: Even me I find this question inappropriate now, I'll let it open for the sake of knowledge for those looking for a chrome theme in the wrong place

Answer (score 3):

The theme is called [Zero Dark Matrix](https://github.com/mauricecruz/chrome-devtools-zerodarkmatrix-theme) and there's a Gist by the author for [Sublime Text](https://gist.github.com/mauricecruz/9e0501a34ec1382fb509). Download it to your Packages folder and activate it inside the Sublime Text preferences.

Comment: He did not ask for the theme for the chrome inspector. He asked the theme for sublime text similar to that of the chrome inspector. I really like that too but unfortunately not found any similar theme for sublime.

Comment: See the second link in my answer

Comment: You are right, Thank you for the answer and sorry for failing to spot the instruction in the first time.
@MattDMo, Thank you  MattDMo for writing down the installation instruction in very easy way that even the beginners will be able to replicate.